# Python: how to obtain only first filename in the directory

Tags: python, path, filenames

I have path for the various directories. Now I want to look into header info of first file in each directory.

Eg: `path = "Users/SDB/case_23/scan_1"`

Now in sub directory `scan_1` I want to check some header information. For this purpose how can I get complete path and name of first file(by name) in a sub directory?

Comment: what do you mean by first file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[os.walk](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)

> `os.walk(top, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=False)`
>   Generate the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up. For each directory in the tree rooted at directory top (including top itself), it yields a 3-tuple `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)`.
>   ...

**Example**

dirs structure

```
$ tree -d
.
└── users
    └── sdb
        └── case_23
            └── scan_1
```

dirs + files structure

```
$ tree
.
├── a.txt
├── b.txt
├── c.txt
└── users
    ├── a.txt
    ├── b.txt
    ├── c.txt
    └── sdb
        ├── a.txt
        ├── b.txt
        ├── c.txt
        └── case_23
            ├── d.txt
            ├── e.txt
            ├── f.txt
            └── scan_1
                ├── a.txt
                ├── b.txt
                └── c.txt
```

python code

```
>>> import os
>>> rootdir = '/tmp/so'
>>> # print full path for first file in rootdir and for each subdir
... for topdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
...     firstfile = sorted(files)[0]
...     print os.path.join(topdir, firstfile)
... 
/tmp/so/a.txt
/tmp/so/users/a.txt
/tmp/so/users/sdb/a.txt
/tmp/so/users/sdb/case_23/d.txt
/tmp/so/users/sdb/case_23/scan_1/a.txt
```

---

Comment: There is no order to listdir so getting whatever *first file*  is may not be possible using it.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham sure, but what does it mean _first file_? Sorted by name, by date, by modification time? ;)

Comment: That is what I asked the OP. Right now I have no idea what the question means so voted to close. Not sure why the complete path is needed either when the OP is already using it!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Agree, that why I gave an "abstract" answer too.

Comment: Thank you for your resposne. Sorry i didnt mention it clearly.

i am looking for first file in a directory by name.

Comment: @tryeverylanguage so you need to improve your question ;)